# Evaluation of $~\Re\{ \exp(x+iy) \}~$ to proceed to use laplacian operator.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, laplacian, eulers-number-e

$$\begin{align}
 f&:=\text{two variable function of }(x,y)\\
 \Delta f&:= {\partial^2 f  \over  \partial x^2}+{\partial^2 f  \over  \partial y^2}\\
 i&:=\text{imaginary number}\\
 f(x,y)&:=\Re\left\{ (x^2-iy^2)(1+i)+ \exp(x+iy )  \right\}\\
 &= \underbrace{\Re\left\{ x^2+x^2 i-iy^2-i^2 y^2+ \exp(x+iy )  \right\}}_{\text{My works begins from this line} } \\
  &=\Re\left\{ x^2+x^2 i-iy^2+ y^2+ \exp(x+iy )  \right\}\\
  &=\Re\left\{ x^2+ y^2+ \underbrace{ \color{red}{\exp(x+iy )}  }_{\text{How can I analyze this?} }   \right\}\\
\end{align}$$

The final objective for me is to evaluate $\Delta f$ from the given equation.

Comment: $\Re e^{x+iy}=e^{x}\Re e^{iy}=e^{x}\cos y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e^{x+iy}=e^x\,e^{iy}$

$e^{iy}=(\cos y+ i\sin y)$

Hence

$e^{x+iy}=(\cos y+ i\sin y)e^x$

Can you get it from here?

Comment: Yes, I had completely missed the first line which you gave..

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\Re \left\{ \exp(x+iy) \right\}  &=\Re  \left\{ e^{x}\cdot e^{iy} \right\}\\&=\Re \left\{ e^{x} \left(\cos(y)+i\sin(y) \right) \right\}\\&=\Re \left\{ e^{x}\cos(y) \right\}\\&=e^{x}\cos(y)  
\end{align}$$ 

The reason I had failed this easy problem is that I had read it as $~ \exp(x+iy) ~$ instead of $~ e^{x+iy} ~$

Comment: @electricalapprentice $\exp(\cdots)$ and $\mathrm e^{\cdots}$ are the same thing.